# Docker "Gracefully stopping" itself during `docker-compose up` but not `docker-compose run --entrypoint`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I start a Docker container with `docker-compose up`, it starts up as usual, but eventually the container automatically exits without anything that I can tell is useful in the verbose log.

When I instead run `docker-compose up --entrypoint run-tests.sh` with the same `docker-compose.yml` configuration (with the same entrypoint set) and the same Dockerfile, the Docker container says "Gracefully stopping" on its own and stops all containers.

The bad behaviour seems to come from running `docker-compose up` instead of the equivalent `docker-compose run`.

The container seems to stay up for varying times before it shuts down. In one instance it stayed up for 7 minutes, different times in others.

**Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?**

Docker versions:

```
Docker version 1.9.0, build 76d6bc9
docker-compose version: 1.5.0
docker-machine version 0.5.0 (HEAD)
```

The `docker-compose --verbose up` log:

```
docker-compose --verbose --project-name monkeycore up monkeycore-autotest
... lots of startup log (let me know if you need to see this) ...
# Scala Play1 Framework tests, not likely relevant
monkeycore-autotest_1 | ~ MonkeyTest...                   PASSED     30s
monkeycore-autotest_1 | ~ WhateverDataTest...             PASSED     33s
monkeycore-autotest_1 | ~ SauceTest...                    PASSED     1 min 44s
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=monkeycore', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 2 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'617bf28c3f7ae3779f383f7e2a96f66e552e92f755a15d07ac6b73329ba3860f')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'-c', u'build.sh && play auto-test'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': None,
             u'CpuShares': 0,
             u'Cpuset': u'',
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'bash', u'-c', u'build.sh && play auto-test'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'4963e9287ed10d587a79f57a52eaf86c07c6947b2119072bd5d68a3ed0eb161e')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': False,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': False,
             u'Cmd': None,
             u'CpuShares': 0,
             u'Cpuset': u'',
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'redis-server',
...
Stopping monkeycore_monkeycore-autotest_1 ...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker stop <- (u'617bf28c3f7ae3779f383f7e2a96f66e552e92f755a15d07ac6b73329ba3860f', timeout=10)
Stopping monkeycore_monkeycore-autotest_1 ... done
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
monkeycore-base:
    build: ../
    dockerfile: "docker/monkeycore/Dockerfile"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8082:8082"
      - "9000:9000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    working_dir: "/path/to/dir"
    volumes:
      - src:dest
    environment:
      LOTS_OF_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES: "defined"

monkeycore-autotest:
    extends:
      service: monkeycore-base
    links:
      - redis
    entrypoint: "run-tests.sh"

redis:
    build: ./redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2338#issuecomment-158202641) for that at Compose's repository.

In the issue someone suggested, as a workaround, to run `docker-compose up -d`. That way containers will keep running even if there's a connection failure. 
To see the container logs just run `docker-compose logs`.

That suggestion solved the problem for now without having to worry to downgrade Compose.

Comment: Could you link to the issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason your docker client lost comunication with you docker engine. Probably some issue on *monkeycore_monkeycore-autotest_1* container caused it.

Check if your docker machine is still running:

```
$ docker machine ls
```

and if your envs variables are set, the 'docker' ones:

```
env | grep -i "docker"
```

Try to restart your docker-machine, reset your env vars

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)" ### or your machine name.
```

and try to run the tests manually inside the container (`docker exec -ti container-name /bin/bash`) to see what is going wrong there.

Comment: I updated the question. I've found out that the bad behaviour happens when running `docker-compose up`, where it doesn't happen when running `docker-compose run --entrypoint` where the same entrypoint is set.

Comment: My docker-machine is running, and I can ssh to it. I can also successfully execute `docker-compose run` and pass those tests, between failures of `docker-compose up` that has the same entrypoint. The problem seems to only be with `docker-compose up`.

Comment: I did not know about that docker-compose issue. I always start docker-compose using `-d` flag.