# Docker - Couldn't connect to Docker daemon

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose, docker-machine

I started getting a

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

but i am not using `docker-machine` (Although i have version 0.5.2 installed)

I am running docker directly in my `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` with `Docker 1.11.0` e `Docker-compose 1.7.0`.

Why am i getting this error? Should i uninstall docker-machine since i don't use it or upgrade it? Is the problem something else?

Comment: Is the `docker` daemon actually running?

Comment: yes otherwise it wouldnt start docker compose. it runs but it looks like it crashes for some reason

Comment: i upgraded docker-machine to version 0.7.0 . let me see if it happens again

Comment: upgrading docker-machine didn't help. i do `sudo service docker status` and docker is still running even after the error msg. How do i uninstall docker-machine?

Comment: meanwhile i am going to try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33814844/977622

Comment: my issue continues

Comment: Your question is missing some relevant information. What is the command you are running that is producing the error? What is your current user running the command? Can you confirm it isn't actually using the machine with the output of `docker-machine ls`?

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to know what might be going on without some more information. But outside of Docker Machine, the error is usually because your user isn't in the `docker` group. By default, the socket doesn't allow users other than `root` to use the socket.

You can find more information and the solution at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group. But usually you just need to add your user to the `docker` group with command `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`.

However, you need to be aware that this is the equivalent of granting root permissions to that user. You are allowing that user to run Docker containers that can mount folders as root.

Comment: my user is already in the docker group... when i run docker-machine ls there are no running vm but there is one that shows an error `machine does not exist` but it is from another project. Can i uninstall docker-machine? how do i do that?

Comment: by the way i am running `docker-compose run --rm web bash` and then inside i am running python selenium and it starts ok, but sometimes it crashes with this error and kills all my containers.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. That error is for a client trying to connect to the daemon. I don't see how that error would happen for when you already have a shell opened for a container namespace. See my comment on your question for additional information. The given information is lacking and doesn't quite make sense yet...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue , had to change the ownership of the `docker` `docker.sock` `docker.pid` from root:root to `$USER:docker` located at `/var/run/` ,since this was a permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon. More useful info from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/477554/789190).

**Giving non-root access**

The docker daemon always runs as the root user, and since Docker version 0.5.2, the docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root, and so, by default, you can access it with sudo.

Starting in version 0.5.3, if you (or your Docker installer) create a Unix group called docker and add users to it, then the docker daemon will make the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group when the daemon starts.

Comment: The default user group of `docker.sock` is docker. But it could be overwritten by -G flag. Why your owner group of `docker.sock` is root?